# Python "from sklearn import svm" leads to SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, scikit-learn, python-import

I am running Python 3.7.0 on macOS, and I have scikit-learn version 0.20.1 installed using pip. I also have numpy and scipy installed.

When I try the following code:

```
from sklearn import svm
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC, \
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .base import _fit_liblinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ..preprocessing import LabelEncoder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._function_transformer import FunctionTransformer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_function_transformer.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..utils.testing import assert_allclose_dense_sparse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 54, in <module>
    from nose.tools import raises as _nose_raises
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nose.core import collector, main, run, run_exit, runmodule
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 153
    print "%s version %s" % (os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]), __version__)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If i just import sklearn (without specifying svm), I get no errors.

Can I get help with this error please?

Comment: Some of those modules point to python 3.7, others python 2.7

Comment: @Chris_Rands Hmm I see that now, how should I go about fixing this?